# How to apply Primefaces effect when component is rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have drag panel and drop panel, and when component is dropped in the drop panel i show a new panel and hide the old panel based on render boolean attribute as follows:

**1- xhtml:**

```
<p:outputPanel id="oldPanel" rendered=#{myBean.old_panel_rendered}> .... </p:outputPanel>
<p:outputPanel id="newPanel" rendered=#{myBean.new_panel_rendered}> .... </p:outputPanel>
```

**2- bean:**

```
old_panel_rendered=true;
new_panel_rendered=false;

public void onComponentDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) { 

        old_panel_rendered=false;
        new_panel_rendered=true;

    }
```

how to execute an effect for newPanel when it gets rendered and execute an effect for oldPanel when it gets unrendered.

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call js function which will apply the effects when a new item droppped:

```
<p:ajax listener="#{bean.onDrop}" onstart="applyEffects();" update="newPanel" />
```

Function is:

```
function applyEffects() {
    var oldPanel = $(document.getElementById('oldPanel'));
    var newPanel = $(document.getElementById('newPanel'));
    oldPanel.css({"display":"none"});//or oldPanel.fadeOut(500) which looks fancy
    newPanel.css({"display":"inline"});
    newPanel.effect("highlight",
            {color:"#87FF7A"}, 1500);
}
```

- Don't forget to give exact client id of components when calling `document.getElementById`. You can detect it via your browser's developer settings. If there will be a problem, you can drop `update="newPanel"` or maybe you can try `update="oldpanel newpanel"`.

To be able to apply it for specific panel:

```
public void onComponentDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) { 
    int id = event.getData();//or sth.similar to getId
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("index", id);
}
```

Upper code adds a parameter to ajax response it can be retrieved by:

```
function applyEffects(xhr,status,args) {
    var oldPanel = $(document.getElementById('oldPanel'));
    var newPanel = $(document.getElementById('newPanel'));
    if(args.id=='oldPanel') {//oldPanel or whatever which equals to eventID
        oldPanel.css({"display":"none"});//or oldPanel.fadeOut(500) which looks fancy
    }
    newPanel.css({"display":"inline"});
    newPanel.effect("highlight",
            {color:"#87FF7A"}, 1500);
}
```

You should call this from `p:ajax oncomplete="applyEffects(xhr,status,args);"`. I am coding directly here, therefore can be few mistakes which can be seen on IDE easily.

Comment: i want to apply the fade out effect only if the oldPanel is displayed not every time the function is executed, how to add a condition to do that.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh are you sure about calling it via `oncomplete`? And don't put this into `document.ready` function. Also put an alert or debug via firebug and make sure it is called or not.

Comment: the ids of the panel is something like notebook_form:blank_panel so i tried the escaping as follows notebook_form\\:blank_panel but it doesn't work too

Comment: So putted an `alert(1);` and saw it is alerted right? If it is that means function called correctly, and if the id is equal to notebook_form:blank `$(document.getElementById('notebook_form:blank'));` should get the correct element.

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh because it has to wait till server's putting parameter job ends that's why oncomplete works.